# Can I get my Dragon Priest masks back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing on xbox and I sold a few of my masks to Niranye. Usually when I sell important items to her, she keeps them even after restocking. Except she didn't keep those. Is there any way I can get them back? Please help if you can!

Answer (score 1):

I sold some of them too and I can't even remember to which merchant. :/ So far I haven't found a regular way to get them back...

Sorry, for the bad news.

---

Since you're playing on the XBox this will not be helpful to you, but for others you lost their masks on the PC version:

I think the only way is to "cheat" by using the console and this command:

```
Player.AddItem <ItemID> <#>
```

Read more about the [console](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)).
And here you can find the [item codes for the masks](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/05/18/skyrim-item-codes/).

Comment: Hey Exa! I doubt this answer will help the asker much, since she explicitly mentioned she's on the xbox. The first part probably would have sufficed. :)

Comment: I'm playing on xbox though, so console codes aren't an option.

Comment: Oh, my bad :o I changed the answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get my last mask back ever since Skyrim came out and to no avail. So sadly currently right now their isn't a way of getting them back.